# how do I compare a 'char' and a 'string' together after user entry

Tags: java

my main goal is to ask a user to enter a letter (assuming it'll always be a-z), tell them back what they entered (eg. "you entered: a"). keep the program running until they entered "q" and then break.("You entered: q", "goodbye!")

```
String letterA = "a";
String guess = null;        
    
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Enter a letter: ");
    guess = myChoclate.next();
    char result = guess.charAt(0);
    if( result == letterA) {
        System.out.println( "You entered: a" );
    } else {
        System.out.println( "You entered: q" ); {
        System.out.println("goodbye!");
        break;     
    }
}
```

end goal:

[image: end goal photo]

Answer (score 0):

You could easily convert the character to a string:

```
char result = guess.charAt(0); 
string resultString=String.valueOf(result );
```

Answer (score 0):

From the image you provided, looks like this is what you are looking for.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter a letter: ");
            char input = scanner.nextLine().charAt(0);
            System.out.println("You entered: " + input);
            if (input == 'q') {
                System.out.println("goodbye!");
                break;
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. Have a great time learning java!!!

Comment: yes, it worked! I'm new to this and I appreciate your help a lot.  I also recreated the same output with a 'do while' loop. it worked too

Comment: 'do {
   System.out.println("Enter a letter: ");
   char stillGuess = myChoclate.next().charAt(0);
   System.out.println("You entered: " + stillGuess);
   if (stillGuess == 'q') {
    System.out.println("goodbye!");
    break;

   
   
 
  }
  } while(true) ;'

Comment: The do while solution looks great too!!!